# Raspberry Pi 3 not booting, new SD card, tried every OS

Tags: pi-3, boot, boot-issues

At this point, I'm beginning to suspect that my Pi is DOA. I know, I know. 'It's probably a problem with the SD card'. But I've tried everything, I have it formatted as FAT32, all the files are in the right place on the card. First I tried ubuntu mate which I downloaded from their website, then with NOOBs and raspbian from the raspberry pi website. CheckSums are all good. Also, I have tried with 2 different SD cards just in case the first one had gone bad.

It simply will not boot, red light is lit, green light stays dark.

Is there any way to get this thing to boot or should I rather return to the shop and get a new one?

Comment: `all the files are in the right place on the card` - how did you put the OS image onto the card?

Comment: I used etcher to mount the Ubuntu mate image on the SD.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Power Supply (PSU) are you using?

Check your PSU has enough power.

Can you try another PSU?

Comment: PSU has 5v 2.4 A out so that's ok. I changed out the pi with a new one, this one is working like a champ.